# Update value by using previous value to increment

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I have a query that inserts a new row and creates a unique date. If there is a conflict, I want to update the row instead.

```
const updateInsight = await Insight.createQueryBuilder("Insight")
    .insert()
    .values({ sales: 1 })
    .onConflict("(date) DO UPDATE SET sales = sales + 1")
    .execute();
```

This is the same as:

```
INSERT INTO "Insight" ("sales") VALUES(1) ON CONFLICT (date) DO UPDATE SET sales = sales + 1;
```

The table looks like this where the date field is `default: NOW()` with `type: Date`:

[image]

Running the query I get the following error:

> "column reference "sales" is ambiguous"

I have tried using Insight.sales = Insight.Sales + 1 in the UPDATE SET, but then I get:

> "missing FROM-clause entry for table "insight\

Comment: `... DO UPDATE SET sales = "Insight".sales + 1;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it worked without ";" at the end.